# Rich Text Content Fields with iTextSharp

Tags: itext, richtext

I'm using iTextSharp to create pdf files on the fly for my users to save on their computers. Currently the way it works is that I had several pdf templates that iTextSharp opens, sets fields from the database and save on user computer.

I'm having real problems with adding rich content into the body field which the users enter using a Rich Text editor (NiceEdit). It contains really simple options such as bullets, bold, italic, font colors, sizes etc. which is all what they need. I tried all possible options out there but nothing seem to help.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(originalReport.ToString());

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(report, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

fields.SetFieldProperty("body", "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_RICHTEXT, null);
fields.SetFieldRichValue("body", bodyValue.ToString());

fields.GenerateAppearances = false;
```

I tried flattening the form but it doesn't display the field at all. If I didn't flatten the form then the field displays the content but with no format at all (even new lines are removed) and if I used the SetField option instead of the SetFieldRichValue I get a string of the html content

I also tried allowing the pdf template field to "Allow Rich Text" from acrobat pro but this gives an exception and halts the pdf :)

Also please note that since I'm using a template that depends on the type of the user, the SetField option is used, I don't create the document from scratch hence I don't use paragraphs which I can get if I used the HTMLWorker and simply add to a document

Any help please?